# JavaScript Problem with separating function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with editing function. I have

```
fetch("path", {
    method: 'GET'
}).then((resp) => {
    return resp.json(); 
}).then((body) => {
    if(body){
        addTable(body, $("#table"));    
        $("#table tr").click(function() {
        //Do something  on tr
          
        })  
    }else{
         // Do something 
     }
}).catch((err) => {
    // not here 
});
```

and I edited it into

```
function sendToServerAndReciveJSON(path, appendTo){

fetch(path, {
    method: 'GET'
}).then((resp) => {
    return resp.json(); 
}).then((body) => {
    if(body){
        addTable(body, appendTo);       
    }else{
       //Do something
    }
}).catch((err) => {
    //not here
});
}
```

and

```
sendToServerAndReciveJSON("path",$("#table"));

$("#table tr").click(function() {
        // Do something on tr  
          
    })
```

I get resources from server fine, but I can't make onclick work at all. On browser console I didn't get any error. What I could change to make it work ? (calling to sendToServerAndReciveJSON and adding onclick is in one function )

Comment: `sendToServerAndReciveJSON` has a fetch call which runs async. So in your last code block adding the click listener is running before that element is added to the dom. You can fix this by returning a Promise from that function and `await`ing it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume `addTable` populates `#table` and since that happens in response to an asynchronous action (fetching from the server), it has not happened when you try to attach the listener to its children.

The following changes to your code should solve your problem:

```
function sendToServerAndReciveJSON(path, appendTo){  
    // return the promise  
    return fetch(path, { 
        method: 'GET'
    }).then((resp) => {
        return resp.json(); 
    }).then((body) => {
        if(body){
            addTable(body, appendTo);       
        }else{
           //Do something
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        //not here
    });
}
    
sendToServerAndReciveJSON("path",$("#table"))
// perform the action when the promise is fullfilled
.then(() => { 
    $("#table tr").click(function() {
            // Do something on tr                    
    })
 });
```